# ASP.Net MVC 5 SPA Template OWin /token results in 'invalid_client'

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

In AngularJS and using Chrome Advanced REST Client I am trying to get the token using the 'password' grant_type from an ASP.Net MVC 5 SPA Visual Studio 2015 Template based project. The project is brand new with no modifications at all.

The endpoint is called using this URL:
http://localhost:55472/Token

```
[Headers]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
[Encoded Payload]
Data:=grant_type%3Dpassword%26username%3Db%40c.d%26password%3DPass123--%26client_id%3Dweb
```

And the result is this:

```
400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

No external login is configured and the user registered using the template application.

I tried different ways to construct the payload like this and got the same result:

```
[Encoded Payload]
grant_type=password&username=b%40c.d&password=Pass123--&client_id=web
```

So out of this, it might be the client is not calling the endpoint properly:

```
var _tokenPath = '/Token';
var data = 'grant_type=password&username=b@c.d&password=Pass123--&client_id=web;
$http.post(_tokenPath, data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(
        function (response) {
            debugger;
            console.log(response);
        },
        function (error) {
            debugger;
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
```

Or there's something not right in the Startup.Auth.cs file which prevents the endpoint from working properly.

How do we get the /Token url working out of the box on the SPA Template for MVC5?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This sounds like a long shot, but the [VS2013 SPA template had the same kind of problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23372772/3585500). Maybe they copied the bogus templates into VS2015, so you need to update from NuGet?

Comment: I get from the logs that it's an invalid client id that is sent in:
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware Error: 0 : clientID is not valid.
This page (https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/2.1.0-rtw-30119-769-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth) on symbol source does shot where the error is logged. What I need to know, the client id is compared against what?

Comment: @ÉtienneBrouillard, Were you able to resolve this and if so, how? I'm having the same issue and I need to get this working.

Comment: @ClaytonHyatt Hi, I never got around that and we resorted on using OAuth2 server on NodeJS for the sake of getting things running.

Comment: That'a a bummer! Thanks for the response. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using [katana](/questions/tagged/katana).

This is technically an obsolete technology and has been superseded by [asp.net-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-5).

I would recommend installing it from http://get.asp.net and trying it from there.

Comment: Yes I do get that. But let's just say the "client" doesn't want to change to ASP.Net 5 and the devs are stucked with this, it still needs resolution right?

Comment: Katana has always been an experiment and never had any LTS planned for it. So... Microsoft will not fix because it was a "developer preview". As for ASP.NET 5 RC1? I think there's a "Go Live" for it.

Comment: [Relevant link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5AndNETCoreRC1InContextPlusAllTheConnect2015News.aspx) and quote: "ASP.NET 5 RC1 is out with .NET Core and has a Go Live License.  This means you can go into production with ASP.NET 5 on Windows or Linux and Microsoft will support you."